# ENUM Regular Expression case insensitive

Tags: java

I have an enum regex ^(TECHNICAL|SUPPORT|ADMINISTRATIVE|BILLING|OTHER), I wanted to make it case insensitive.

I tried a few ways by using this as reference, but nothing worked
 Regex:
    a(?i)bc
Matches:
    a       # match the character 'a'
    (?i)    # enable case insensitive matching
    b       # match the character 'b' or 'B'
    c       # match the character 'c' or 'C'

Regex:
    a(?i)b(?-i)c
Matches:
    a        # match the character 'a'
    (?i)     # enable case insensitive matching
    b        # match the character 'b' or 'B'
    (?-i)    # disable case insensitive matching
    c        # match the character 'c'

Regex:
    a(?i:b)c
Matches:
    a       # match the character 'a'
    (?i:    # start non-capture group 1 and enable case insensitive matching
      b     #   match the character 'b' or 'B'
    )       # end non-capture group 1
    c       # match the character 'c'

Comment: What have your searches for a solution turned up? How are they not working for you?

Comment: Regex:
    a(?i)bc
Matches:
    a       # match the character 'a'
    (?i)    # enable case insensitive matching
    b       # match the character 'b' or 'B'
    c       # match the character 'c' or 'C'

Regex:
    a(?i)b(?-i)c
Matches:
    a        # match the character 'a'
    (?i)     # enable case insensitive matching
    b        # match the character 'b' or 'B'
    (?-i)    # disable case insensitive matching
    c        # match the character 'c'

Answer (score 0):

To make RegExp case-insensitive, just add `(?i)` to the beginning:

```
boolean res = "techNICAL".matches("(?i)^(TECHNICAL|SUPPORT|ADMINISTRATIVE|BILLING|OTHER)$");
```

Output:

> true

Demo at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CWCEkM/1)